# How to cover all but one div with frosted glass effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have 2 divs, I moved 1 div to hover above all other divs using `position: absolute` like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.block2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.block3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='block1'>Block 1</>
  <div class='block2'>Block 2</>
  <div class='block3'>Block 3</>
</div>
```

Now I'd like to add a frosted glass to all the divs except `block3`. I know the frosted glass effect can be done by something like `filter: blur(10px)`, but how can I modify `block3` class to apply this effect to all other divs? In other words I want `block3` to be clear, everywhere else should be blurred. Surely adding `filter: blur(10px)` to all other divs are not allowed because in reality I could have block4, block5 etc.

EDIT: thanks for all the help, what I wanted was to have any single block unblurred, and all other blocks blurred. So Marc's answer is correct.

Comment: "Surely adding filter: blur(10px) to all other divs are not allowed."  Why? It seems like you have some constraints that you haven't described.

Comment: Because in reality I could have block4, block5...... and it is not possible to manually add `filter` to all of them.

Comment: just add a `.frosted` or `.clear` class and apply to the elements you want

Comment: Sure it is. `.wrapper > div:not(:last-child) { ... }`

Comment: you can't achieve what your asking by css only.
 for css can only effect forward and not backward

Comment: Do you only need this to work for block3? Or do you want to be able to blur / de-blur any block during runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the new CSS I added, which excludes the `<div>` with a class of `block3`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.block2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.block3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
}

div.wrapper > div:not(.block3) {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='block1'>Block 1</div>
  <div class='block2'>Block 2</div>
  <div class='block3'>Block 3</div>
</div>
```

If you're goal is to hide the ***last*** `.block` element, as others have assumed, then you could use the following instead:

```
div.wrapper > div:not(:last-child) {
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Comment: But this answer also works when you add an unknown number of divs... only `.block3` isn't blurred.

Comment: @Ouroborus, what gives you that impression?  There is nothing in the OP's question that says he/she wants to hide the *last* block. In fact, OP's 2nd comment implies that if he adds `block4` and `block5`, he wants to blur them too. I'm not sure who gave the downvote, but it seems unwarranted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this is all possible with CSS.

To create your frosted glass effect use a CSS class selector *="class" (equivalent to [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)) which selects all elements whose class contains at least one substring "block".

```
[class*="block"] {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Then when you hover over a div, override the styles with this:

```
[class*="block"]:hover {
  filter: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User hover and target the element

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper:hover > .block {
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.wrapper:hover > .block:hover {
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='block'>Block 1</div>
  <div class='block'>Block 2</div>
  <div class='block'>Block 3</div>
</div>
```

if you want it hard coded

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper > .block {
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.wrapper > .block3{
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='block'>Block 1</div>
  <div class='block'>Block 2</div>
  <div class='block block3'>Block 3</div>
</div>
```